# What command should I use with curl in terminal if I want to download an image from a website and put it in a certain folder?

Tags: command-line

I have seen

```
curl -o project/folder/image.png -OL example.com/image.png
```

Would this command work?

Edit: I figured it out

Comment: oO Have you even tried ?

Comment: I did shortly after making this post. Sorry Gilles